# Amadeus flight-offers search GET API won't return flights for AA

Tags: amadeus

I'm learning to use the Amadeus API...
I'm able to search flights using "flight-offers-search", but as the title states, if I restrict results to American Airlines (AA), it returns nothing.
There absolutely are AA flights from DFW on the specified day (I'm on one), so not sure why it would fail.
So far I am unable to return ANY flights on ANY day, if "includedAirlineCodes=AA" is specified.
What is special about American Airlines?  What am I missing?

```
url <- "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=DFW&destinationLocationCode=SAN&departureDate=2021-09-03&travelClass=ECONOMY&adults=1&max=5&currencyCode=USD&includedAirlineCodes=AA"
```

Comment: Why not ask the developer support of that API what you are doing wrong?

Comment: Because their documentation says to post to Stack Overflow with technical questions.
I'll reach out and see if they can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content from American Airlines is not included in the Self-Service APIs as described in the [API overview](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search).